# Gitlab refuse http

Tags: git, http, gitlab, connection, updates

After serverals update on gitlab(last week). Current version 13.6.3.

We re facing issue. Gitlab randomly drops http connection(refuse port 80 communication).
Not able to git clone/push/pull for http: "git clone http://...." .

Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused

But on the other-hand, https or port 443 working without any problem.

Nothing to see in logs, or we re not able to find something.

Is there any way how to debug this problem ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the problem from the output of following commands. It's very

```
traceroute yourgitlabdomain.com
curl http://yourgitlabdomain.com/cdn-cgi/trace
curl https://yourgitlabdomain.com/cdn-cgi/trace
curl -svo /dev/null https://yourgitlabdomain.com
```

I assume you're trying to do a plain http connection on the backend. If so, you'll need to proceed to Supporting proxied SSL in the [Omnibus Nginx documentation.](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#supporting-proxied-ssl)

Comment: we get this when it is in normal conditions, redirect to https 

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

But when it randomly drops:

Failed to connect to port 80: Connection refused